# Query to return first date of missing date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for help with a query using SQL 2008 R2...  I have a table with client and date fields.  Most clients have a record for most dates, however some don't.
For example I have this data:

```
CLIENTID     DT
1            5/1/14
1            5/2/14
2            5/3/14
3            5/1/14
3            5/2/14
```

I can find the missing dates for each `CLIENTID` by creating a `temp table` with all possible dates for the period and then joining that to each `CLIENTID` and `DT` and only selecting where there is a `NULL`.

This is what I can get easily for the date range 5/1/14 to 5/4/14:

```
CLIENTID     DTMISSED
1            5/3/14
1            5/4/14
2            5/1/14
2            5/2/14
2            5/4/14
3            5/3/14
3            5/4/14
```

However I want to group each consecutive missed period together and get the beginning of each period and the length.

For example, if I use the date range 5/1/14 to 5/4/14 I'd like to get:

```
CLIENTID     DTSTART    MISSED
1            5/3/14     2
2            5/1/14     2
2            5/4/14     1
3            5/3/14     2
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: hmm why you have '3', '5/1/14', '1' in last example? I think in this example it should be skiped?

Comment: too right! I fixed the table - thanks for catching that...

Comment: as I see now you can go one by one row and update additional column, which you will use for grouping (not very nice choice, but cant think of something better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fascinating how more elegantly and also mere efficiently this kind of problems can be solved in 2012.

First, the tables:

```
create table #t (CLIENTID int,    DT date)
go
insert #t values
(1,            '5/1/14'),
(1,            '5/2/14'),
(2,            '5/3/14'),
(3,            '5/1/14'),
(3,            '5/2/14')
go

create table #calendar (dt date)
go
insert #calendar values ('5/1/14'),('5/2/14'),('5/3/14'),('5/4/14')
go
```

Here's the 2008 solution:

```
;with x as (
    select *, row_number() over(order by clientid, dt) as rn
    from #calendar c
    cross join (select distinct clientid from #t) x 
    where not exists (select * from #t where c.dt=#t.dt and x.clientid=#t.clientid)
),
y as (
    select x1.*, x2.dt as x2_dt, x2.clientid as x2_clientid
    from x x1
    left join x x2 on x1.clientid=x2.clientid and x1.dt=dateadd(day,1,x2.dt)
),
z as (
    select *, (select sum(case when x2_dt is null then 1 else 0 end) from y y2 where y2.rn<=y.rn) as grp
    from y
)
select clientid, min(dt), count(*)
from z
group by clientid, grp
order by clientid
```

Compare it to 2012:

```
;with x as (
    select *, row_number() over(order by dt) as rn
    from #calendar c
    cross join (select distinct clientid from #t) x 
    where not exists (select * from #t where c.dt=#t.dt and x.clientid=#t.clientid)
),
y as (
    select x1.*, sum(case when x2.dt is null then 1 else 0 end) over(order by x1.clientid,x1.dt) as grp
    from x x1
    left join x x2 on x1.clientid=x2.clientid and x1.dt=dateadd(day,1,x2.dt)
)
select clientid, min(dt), count(*)
from y
group by clientid, grp
order by clientid
```

Comment: Wow Dean that is some ninja stuff!

Comment: Except I need it to show some clients who don't have any records in #t and should basically show as missed 4 starting 5/1...  I guess I have to beef up `x`.

Comment: Correct. In x CTE join some customers with some dates, to create a matrix. Which customers with which dates, you do the select :)